# TYPO3 10 LTS: Make .scss files editable in Backend, just like .css files

Tags: configuration, typo3, typo3-10.x

In TYPO3 v10 LTS, as a backend Admin user, I can edit `.css` files  in the "file explorer" (that is available in the Filelist module. I don't know the correct terms). See Screenshot.

[image: typo3 css files- edit dialog is present]

When the file has a .css extension (1), I can click on the "Edit content" icon (2), and an editor window opens.

---

*However*, when I rename the file to `.scss` (1) I can no longer edit the file. The "Edit" Icon is no longer available (2). See below:

[image: typo3 css files- edit dialog is not present]

Is there a way to also make `.scss` files editable, just like `.css` files? Some setting, or TypoScript/PageTS Config parameter? I can also patch the source code if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `$GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’][‘SYS’][‘textfile_ext’]`
> Type: text
> Default:  ‘txt,ts,typoscript,html,htm,css,tmpl,js,sql,xml,csv,xlf,yaml,yml’
> Text file extensions. Those that can be edited. Executable PHP files
> may not be editable if disallowed!

[Source: TYPO3 Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/GlobalValues/Typo3ConfVars/SYS.html#globals-typo3-conf-vars-sys-textfile-ext)

But keep in mind, that a change in a SCSS file needs to be processed somehow, as the browser needs CSS.

Comment: Thanks! I've opened `public/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`, and added this key: `'textfile_ext' => 'txt,ts,typoscript,html,htm,css,scss,tmpl,js,sql,xml,csv,xlf,yaml,yml',` - worked for me, immediately, without refreshing any TYPO3 cache.